# Получение элементов ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ComboBox, в котором 2 элемента.

Как мне проверить, что именно выбрал пользователь?

Comment: Забиндить SelectedItem на подходящее свойство вашей VM, разумеется.

Comment: @VladD, а можно пример?

Comment: Сейчас напишу, момент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример:

VM-уровень:

```
class Entry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Entry> Entries { get; private set; }

    Entry selectedEntry;
    Entry SelectedEntry
    {
        get { return selectedEntry; }
        set { selectedEntry = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

View-уровень:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntry}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с ответом @VladD, но есть другой, "рабоче-крестьянский" метод через свойство Tag элемента ComboboxItem, который очень полезен, когда прямой Binding к данным неудобен (Например нужно добавить первым элементом строчку "Все варианты", которой, разумеется, нет в Binding Source):

```
  //заполнение первого элемента
 ComboBoxItem first_cbi = new ComboBoxItem();
                 first_cbi.Content = "Все отделы";
                 cb_Departments.Items.Add(first_cbi);

//заполнение остальных элементов из чего-нибудь IEnumerable
foreach (Department dep in Departments)
             {
                 ComboBoxItem cbi = new ComboBoxItem();
                 cbi.Tag = dep;
                 cbi.Content = dep.Name;
                 cb_Departments.Items.Add(cbi);
             }
//--

//Обработчик выбора элемента
private void cb_Departments_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if(cb_Departments.SelectedIndex=0)
   {
       //выбрана опция "Все отделы"
   }
  else
   {
     ComboBoxItem cbi=(ComboBoxItem)cb_Departments.SelectedItem;
     Department selectedDepartment=(Department)cbi.Tag;
      //selectedDepartment - выбранный отдел, делаем с ним что хотим.
   }
}
```

Comment: Для таких целей лучше использовать `CompositeCollection` (наподобие [этого](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18672026/276994)).